# lshw and /proc/meminfo show different values

Tags: linux, memory, hardware-detection

I have an old server from a friend (so I'm not too familiar with its specs) and am confused by the various ways system statistics get shown.
The machine is running Ubuntu 22.04:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-desktop 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There are two 4GB RAM modules installed but depending on where I look I see only 4GB in total:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:        3921416 kB

ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] kernel: Memory: 3747444K/4122476K available (20480K kernel code, 4265K rwdata, 13180K rodata, 4792K init, 17396K bss, 374772K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.182659] kernel: x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
```

This coincides with values seen in top and the [resource management window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt9Pj.png)

However the system is (somewhat?) aware of 8 GB RAM installed:

```
sudo lshw -short | grep memory
/0/0                                  memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/c                                  memory         8GiB Systemspeicher
/0/c/0                                memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/c/1                                memory         4GiB DIMM DDR4 Synchron Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2667 MHz (0,4 ns)
/0/e                                  memory         768KiB L1 Cache
/0/f                                  memory         4MiB L2 Cache
/0/10                                 memory         16MiB L3 Cache
```

Which happens to be the value shown in the [Ubuntu systems window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTHRW.png).

According to the dmesg output, and from what I see elsewhere, only 4GB are available. Considering the size of swap this was most likely also the case on installation (meant as throwaway OS I didn't care about details back then and expected 8GB RAM plus according swap...)

Is this right, and if so, where does that discrepancy come from?

And is there a way for me to fix this in the sense of having all 8 GB available?

Comment: "There are 2 4GB RAM" : Is it 24GB, 4GB or 8GB ?

Comment: two 4 GB modules. Edited to make the it clearer.

Comment: If it is really old, maybe memory remapping is still optional in BIOS. I suggest checking for an option to enable it.

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`?

Comment: @DanielB I checked the BIOS but found nothing suitable. The CPU also is a Ryzen 7 2700 from 2018, so I guess it's not too old.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ```BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-15-generic root=UUID=b8818956-22f3-43e7-b15a-fbcb82137c33 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7```

Comment: So then the usual error remains: one of the sticks is broken or improperly installed.

Comment: Yeah, now I feel silly...1 module is dead, and I actually didn't expect the machine to boot at all in such a case, hence never even thought about checking...
Thank you very much for your help and effort :)
I'd still be interested in an explanation of the different values shown. The BIOS did show both modules as well while eg memtest only the one functional. I suspect that meminfo/lshw just report different stuff? (functionality vs existence of the module?)
Also, do you have best practices for what to do with such a question, eg plainly delete it?